# android call Logs Date insertion

Tags: android

I am trying to insert Call Logs in inbox programmatically but I am using getcontentresolver() for insertion. but when i am trying to insert date at that time exception is thrown.
i have String variable "date" in which date is "2011-11-04".  and i am passing it to values.put(CallLog.Calls.DATE, callDate);

my code is here

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, callnumber);
values.put(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, callLogName);
values.put(CallLog.Calls.DATE, callDate);
values.put(CallLog.Calls.DURATION, callDuration);
values.put(CallLog.Calls.TYPE, callType);
getContentResolver().insert(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,values);
```

Exception is "java numberformate exception"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CallLog.Calls.DATE - The date the call occured, in milliseconds since the epoch

Type: INTEGER (long)

Convert your date to milliseconds.

```
        String date = "2011-11-13";

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date newDate = null;
    try {
        newDate = sdf.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
     cal.setTime(newDate);
     cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check call date format its format should be compatible
convert calldate to proper format
here i convert calldate use this code may be its helpfull

```
    public static void insertPlaceholderCall(ContentResolver contentResolver, String number){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, number);
    values.put(CallLog.Calls.DATE, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(CallLog.Calls.DURATION, 0);
    values.put(CallLog.Calls.TYPE, CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE);
    values.put(CallLog.Calls.NEW, 1);
    values.put(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, "");
    values.put(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE, 0);
    values.put(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL, "");
    Log.d(TAG, "Inserting call log placeholder for " + number);
    contentResolver.insert(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, values);
}
```

also add these permission

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: thanks for answer but i am trying to insert call logs into CallLog.Calls.DATE  i have date in String format.and i am not able to do this

Comment: put your exception form logcat

Comment: Sam in your answer you are putting current date and time but i have details of last few days of call-Log as i have sync before. so i need to put exact date in CallLog.Calls.DATE and i have that date in this format "2011-11-01" its a String variable

Comment: @HarshTrivedi So where the problem u do right things. may be its not regarding date problem tell me the exception full details from logcat